# Set error message of a field by jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MVC, Razor.  I have an input control :

```
 <input name="CustomerName" id="CustomerName" type="hidden" value="" data-val-altid="CustomerName">
```

The data annotations for this field are firing after a post back not before as they should (don't know why)

So, i wanted to create validation at the client side via jQuery like this in document.ready:

```
$('#CustomerName').prop('required', true);
```

But i don't know how to put error message for this control, can someone please help..

Comment: use google for such things. you can find dozen articles with many examples.

Comment: I searched but couldn't find anything that's why i took the pain of formatting a question here

Answer (score 0):

Okay just added required="required" title="Customer Name is required" in the input field and it worked, still not able to figure why the data annotations won't work for just this control

Answer (score 0):

For Jquery validation you can use the following way:

- On submit button click im calling a javascript function where i am checking the required textbox fields, based on which im returning either true or false.

function Validate()
{

if($('#CustomerName').val() == '')

{

return false;
}

else {

return true;

}

}

Comment: <input type="submit" value="Save" onclick="return Validate();" />